# What's the resolution / image sizes to use for barImage on Ti.UI.Window?

Tags: javascript, uinavigationbar, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

basically, I want to do something like Instagram

[image]

(http://avocadosocial.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/IMG_3921.jpg) related to the `barImage` of the starting window. My logo, which I want to put there, is also more or less in this dimensions (around 16:9). I'm not able to find the correct resolutions/dimension information (ideal `height` and `width`) to use for the `barImage` property.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think that there is not barImage used in the link you provided and still you can achieve the perfect result by following these steps:

For Window title, you can customise it like this:

```
"Window[platform=ios]": {
    backgroundColor : 'white',
    navTintColor : 'white',
    barColor : Alloy.CFG.COLOR_PRIMARY,
    titleAttributes : {
        color : 'white',
        font : { fontFamily : 'font', fontSize : 18 },   // see how to use custom fonts in Appc Docs
    },
    swipeToClose : false
}
```

- titleAttributes is what applied to the title of window in navigation stack.
- For left/right nav buttons, I prefer to use this type of code:

Do not use ImageView in buttons, use Button and set the title of it using fontAwesome or Material Icons font file.

```
<RightNavButton>
                    <View>
                        <Button class="materialFont" title="\ue5cd" onClick="close" />
                    </View>
                </RightNavButton>
```

Do remember to use the Button inside View, otherwise your font won't applied to button and you will see some weird image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! I fully agree that you can solve it like this - in the case of the instagram example at least (when you want to use a special font, f.e.). In my case I have a logo as an image (png) and I want to use the image at this place, out of this reason I need to know in which dimensions I've to provide the image that it fits into the navigation bar. Do you have any ideas on using an image for the `barImage` property?

Comment: If your only option is to use image in bar, then make 1x, 2x, 3x copies of bar image and bar height is I think 64dp, so you can decide accordingly.

Comment: I couple of months ago, in an earlier state of development I did that already and created lot of different variations of the logo, but it never fitted very well. That's why I wanted to search for the correct dimensions. Let's say: `barImage` within the NavigationBar of an iPhone 6 should be around `64px` height and max `120px` width. I was searching for this kind of information, but I see it's not so easy as expected. Nevertheless, thanks a already!

Comment: its 64dp, not 64px, when you will design your images - you will be dealing with pixels, so take care of converting dp into pixels. 
So for iPhones with 2x sizes, the barImage will be of 128px = height and 640px = width = iPhone screen width. I hope this helps you to create perfect bar Images.

Comment: Now we're coming to the solution area, I think. :-) You are right, it's about points and not pixels. According to sources like http://ivomynttinen.com/blog/the-ios-7-design-cheat-sheet or http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html the NavigationBar itself (without StatusBar) seems to be 44dp. Together with StatusBar it's 64dp. For a no-retina screen that means, it's 44px height - right? Based on that my logo has to be (in the minimum version, let's say normal logo.png) maybe 40px height. Then I go up with logo@2x.png and logo@3x.png... right? (I work with Sketch)

Comment: Exactly! This is not so tough task but all you need to take care is of converting *dp* to pixels while creating images. You will have to use only 3 images - 1x, 2x and 3x. Also note that most of the iPhones are 2x so better try your image on iPhone 5 (s or c) or 6.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @PrashantSaini. That makes sense! I'll try it asap. :-)